# sorting coding Issues

Tags: python

I've a text file with data like the one below;

```
South-America; Raul; Segio; 31; 34234556
Africa; Kofi; Adama; 27; 65432875
North-America; James; Watson; 29; 43552376
Africa; Koko; Stevens; 23; 23453243
Europe; Anthony; Baker; 32; 89878627
```

Comment: OK, where is query that insert data in your table?

Comment: You should double-check the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Well the reasons this is happening is because the create line does not fall within the for loop. Because `Europe` is the last item in the table, it is the only one which is executed.

You want to move the execution within the for loop, along the lines of:

```
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="root",passwd="12345678*",db="TESTDB1")
cursor = mydb.cursor()

with open('data.txt', 'r') as z:
   for line in z:
      m = {}
      (m['0'], m['1'], m['2'], m['3']) = line.split(";")
      Table = m['0']

      sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +Table+ " (name char(40), lastname char(40), age int (3), code int (10))"
      cursor.execute(sql)
mydb.close()
```

i.e. first create the database, then loop over inserting each of the tables you desire, then close it.

Another way would be to just indent the bottom half of your code.

Comment: Tried it and got, ..........._mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-afi (name char(40), lastname char(40), petname char (40))' at line 1")

Comment: I suspect that may be something to do with you using dashes in some of the table names... Try removing the daahes